# How to fix this "i need decimal places so for ".41" is gives 41 but for "9.41" it gives 40."

Tags: c, cs50

I'm solving cs50 pset1, I need first 2 decimal places.
I'm trying to get it by converting the float I get from the user to int, then substracting it from float and then multiplying by 100 to get 2 decimal places

for ex input 9.41
after subustracting i get .410000
but when multiplying by 100 i get 40.9999 as output
whereAS I need exact 41 so i can convert to int

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<cs50.h>
    #include<math.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        int i = 0;
        float number = get_float("Enter change: ");
        printf("%f \n",number);
        int integer = (int)number;
        printf("%i \n",integer);
        float change = number - integer;
        printf("%f \n",change);
        change = change * 100;
        printf("%f \n",change);
        int n = (int)change;

        printf("%i \n",n);
    }
```

**expected:**

```
Enter change: 9.41
9.410000 
9 
0.410000 
41.000000 
41
```

**actual:**

```
Enter change: 9.41
9.410000 
9 
0.410000 
40.999985 
40
```

Comment: This is why you should not use floats for currency.

Comment: `%f` -> `%.2f` and also read the specs of `printf`, especially the variations of the `%f` format specifier, and  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken.

Comment: So if i cant use floating points  due to their imprecision, then what are other options?

Comment: Quick (possibly innacurate) fix: before converting to int add `0.5` --- `int n = (int)(change + 0.5);`

Comment: @RohitJain use integer for currency. Store amount of cents. This avoids all problems with inaccuracies.

Comment: @AndreasH.: Using integer does not “avoid all problems with inaccuracies.” Integer arithmetic cannot represent the unit price of products sold three for a dollar. When computing sales tax, inaccuracies will occur and must be worked around by the programmer. Inaccuracies due to overflow may occur and must be guarded against.

Comment: @EricPostpischil. Working with integers just forces the programmer to employ/think about the correct rounding mode, as e.g. either mandated by rules or quasi standards (bankers rounding). So true, the programmer has to work around the issues, but I think there is no way around it (no matter how you implement financial calculations). Even if it may sounded so, I did not mean that the problems with inaccuracies just vanish automatically.

Comment: Thank you, I just rounded it off to the nearest integer before using